# Webpack alias in Laravel Mix to node_modules

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I would like to use an alias in VUE.JS in a Laravel 5.8 project to import css and js I have in my module.

*webpack.mix.js*

```
mix.webpackConfig({
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'alias':  path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            '~myModule/src'
        )
     }
   }
});
```

In my VUE App.js I would like import the css folder and I wrote:

*resources/js/app.js*

```
// css files
import 'alias/lib/css'

// js files
import 'alias/lib/script'
```

But I'm wrong something becouse the alias is not resolved:

> ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'alias/lib/css' in...

Can you help me to fix the issue?

Comment: why you are using tilde `~` in `path.resolve` function?

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko, I try with and without ~ but  not works. I thought ~ was an alias to node_modules.

Comment: are you trying to specify a path to node_modules as a relative path? Like this `path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/myModule/src' )`

Comment: and as I see webpack config in Laravel Mix, you should be able to import files from a module that you are interested in like this: `import 'myModule/src/lib/script.js' `

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko Thanks Andrii for your help. That's true Laravel MIx works well using import 'myModule/src/lib/script' (without .js it import all the folder). But I prefer to use an alias to update all the url in just one place if I replace the module version: it's just to have a clean code. Maybe my webpack.mix.js is incorrect or it's not loaded properly.

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko I got it!! Thanks for your help! The issue was in webpack.mix.js loading. I'm gong to answer to my own question for details! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

After so many attempts I got the issue. The code was good but I was missing to load the webpack.mix.js properly:

[From Laravel Mix documentation:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix)

> The webpack.mix.js file is your entry point for all asset compilation. Think of it as a light configuration wrapper around Webpack. Mix tasks can be chained together to define exactly how your assets should be compiled.

But if you are using *npm run watch* it is not (re)loaded before to compile new changed assets. This means:

if you are in watch mode (*npm run watch*) exit and restart it to load new updated *webpack.config.js* if you changed it.

Finally it worked! And it resolve new alias properly!

Here the final config I used in *webpack.config.js*:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'aliasName':  path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            'node_modules/MyModule/src/'
        )
     }
   }
});
```

Another alternative is:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules'
        ],
        alias: {
            'aliasName' : 'MyModule/src/'
        }
    }
});
```

Then in my Vue component (or in vue app.js, just in case)

```
 <template>

     <myModule-component></myModule-component>

 </template>

    require('aliasName/lib/css');      // to load full css directory
    require('aliasName/lib/script');   // to load full js directory

    import MyModuleComponent from 'aliasName/widgets/MyModuleComponent.vue'

    ...
    export default {
        ...
        components: {
           'myModule-component': MyModuleComponent
        }
```